# function that checks for balanced parenthesis in python

Tags: recursion, parentheses

> Write a function is_balanced(chars) that takes a string and determines
> if the various bracketing characters (e.g. ( ), [ ], and { } ) are
> balanced returning True when balanced and False when not. In a
> properly formatted Python program these characters should always be in
> balance unless they are within string literals. Here are some legal
> configurations you might find assuming you ignore all of the
> characters that are not bracketing characters (we have included extra
> spaces for clarity):
>
> { ( [ ] ) ( [ ( ) ] ) } ( { { ( ) } } [ ] ) ( { [ ] } ) On the other
> hand, these are not legal: ( ( [ ] )    # Missing a close parenthesis
> ) (          # The close parenthesis comes before the open parenthesis
> { ( } )      # The parentheses and braces are improperly nested Your
> solution should be based on the insight that a string consisting only
> of bracketing characters is balanced if and only if one of the
> following conditions holds:
>
> The string is empty The string contains "( )", "{ }" or "[ ]" as a
> substring and is balanced if you remove that substring. To do this
> you'll want to use the replace string method.

What I have so far:

```
def is_balanced(chars):
while len(chars) != 0:
    if chars[0] == ")":
        return True
    elif chars[0] == "(":
        is_balanced(chars[1:])
return False
```

I keep getting a time limit exceeded error.

Comment: Your loop is infinite for everything except the base cases. `while` is not the same as `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method that check braces that act like a stack.

```
def has_valid_braces(text):
    open_braces = "[{("
    close_braces = "]})"
    stack = []

    for char in text:
        if char in open_braces:
            stack.append(char)
        elif char in close_braces:
            if not stack or open_braces.index(stack.pop()) != close_braces.index(char):
                return False

    return len(stack) == 0
```